# Maven compiler plugin failure?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, fedora

This question has been asked in so many ways before I'm sure.

Particulars of my environment:

- `Fedora 19`
- `Oracle JDK 6u45` (installed per http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-6-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)
- `Maven 3.0.5` (unpacked from .zip into /opt/apache-maven-3.0.5)

The following submitted for review (too large to paste and format here):

- Console out from build attempt with `mvn -e`, http://pastebin.com/qmNKVYjH
- The `pom.xml` files for the `parent` and for `common` project where failure occurs
  ** parent, http://pastebin.com/p1nJaxDt
  ** common, http://pastebin.com/KQh88RBM

Here are some things I verified about my environment...

```
[jenkins@lx64etseapp04 workspace]$ set | grep JAVA
JAVA=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45

[jenkins@lx64etseapp04 workspace]$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 05:51:28-0800)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.1-200.fc19.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

[jenkins@lx64etseapp04 workspace]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

[jenkins@lx64etseapp04 workspace]$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_45

[jenkins@lx64etseapp04 workspace]$ which java
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java

[jenkins@lx64etseapp04 workspace]$ set | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin:/opt/TEE-CLC-11.0.0:/opt/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:   /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin:/opt/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/jenkins/.local/bin:/var/lib/jenkins/bin
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/kde4/plugins:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins
local cmd PATH=$PATH:/sbin;
if [[ -z "${CDPATH:-}" || "$cur" == ?(.)?(.)/* ]]; then
for i in ${CDPATH//:/'
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin type $1 &>/dev/null
COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( PATH="$PATH:/sbin" lsmod |         awk '{if (NR != 1) print $1}' )" -- "$1" ))
local PATH=$PATH:/sbin;
local PATH="$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin";
COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W         "$( PATH="$PATH:/sbin" lspci -n | awk '{print $3}')" -- "$cur" ))
local PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin;
COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W         "$( PATH="$PATH:/sbin" lsusb | awk '{print $6}' )" -- "$cur" ))

[jenkins@lx64etseapp04 workspace]$ uname -r
3.11.1-200.fc19.x86_64

[jenkins@lx64etseapp04 workspace]$
```

**UPDATE**
I think my problem may be about maven-compiler-plugin, but I cannot rule out environment configuration.  The maven-compiler-plugin is failing as you see above.

**Why is Maven saying it wants to use JRE rather than JDK?**  The JDK is indeed installed!

Here's some `mvn -X` output...

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1, parent: $
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE(3.0.x)-JavaProjects/workspace/common
[DEBUG]   (f) buildDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE(3.0.x)-JavaProjects/workspace/common/target
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE(3.0.x)-JavaProjects/workspace/common/target/classes, /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/etp/commons/commons-log-persi$
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE(3.0.x)-JavaProjects/workspace/common/src/main/java]
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerArgument = -Xlint:all
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerId = javac
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerVersion = 1.6
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) forceJavacCompilerUse = false
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = true
[DEBUG]   (f) generatedSourcesDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE(3.0.x)-JavaProjects/workspace/common/target/generated-sources/annotations
[DEBUG]   (f) maxmem = 512m
[DEBUG]   (f) meminitial = 128m
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile {execution: default-compile}
[DEBUG]   (f) optimize = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE(3.0.x)-JavaProjects/workspace/common/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) projectArtifact = com.etse:etse-common:jar:3.0.3-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = true
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMultiThreadWarning = false
[DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.6
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.6
[DEBUG]   (f) useIncrementalCompilation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = true
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@2df30035
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@2df30035
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[DEBUG] Source directories: [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ETSE(3.0.x)-JavaProjects/workspace/common/src/main/java]
```

Comment: Post your `pom.xml` and the actual output of `mvn -X`.

Comment: My `pom.xml` is huge.  Are you looking for what the output from the maven-compiler-plugin is?

Comment: My maven does the same thing for me.  The JDK uses the JRE to run.  The JDK is the JRE plus a compiler and tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post turned out to provide the clue to the fix I needed for my particular environment and multi-module Maven build.

- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201307.mbox/%3CCALcFPWELXJ2ifEhZswWE57HRkjfKRsAU=sn=ViZfJse95u7HBA@mail.gmail.com%3E

I downgraded the version of the `maven-compiler-plugin` from `3.1` to `2.3.2` and my build continued without failure.

Not sure what the root cause really was (guess is that compiler warning perhaps being treated as an error).  `mvn -e` was not very helpful for me, nor was `mvn -X`.  Only after many Google search attempts did I find the above post.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the `mvn --version` output, it is using the Java installation that you told it to use; i.e. the one you installed in `/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45`.

> Why is Maven saying it wants to use JRE rather than JDK?

It is not saying that.  It is simply telling you what it has set its JAVA_HOME variable to, and that setting looks correct for a JDK install.

I expect that the cause of your maven-compiler-plugin failure is something else.  But you've not included the information required to work out what that is.  There should be some earlier output (listing the compilation errors!).  If that doesn't help, rerun the `mvn` command with the `-e` option (as suggested by the plugin failure message!!) and tell us what it says.

---

In general, if it is a bad idea to focus too early on one particular theory of why your build is failing, and a *worse* idea to only show the people you want to help you the evidence that relates to *your* theory.

Comment: This (was) the end of a very long week troubleshooting and fixing all manner of problems related to converting a Windows / TFS / Jenkins / Maven build to Fedora / TEE-CLC / Jenkins / Maven build. What used to work flawlessly on Windows is subject to pain of configuration on Linux. The Pom.xml for this project builds fine on the former but not the latter. There are no compilation issues w/ source. So `-e` or `-X` will show nothing.

Comment: I got a -1 for the original title and for not being forthcoming with more information to help you help me... so this is my second attempt.  Apologies, but this has been a long road to hoe.  Lots of learning and frustration.

Comment: I have nothing to add to the suggestions that I have already made.